# Bot is not able to edit message (Telebot/Multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, telebot

I'm sure i'm using the same id, but when send_message_process tries to edit the message with the provided message id gotten on queue, i get the following error:

Error editing message: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found... Trying again

```
import telebot
import threading
import requests
import re
import multiprocessing
from queue import Queue
from telebot import types
from defs_helper import *
from datetime import datetime
import time as tm



gpid = 'xxxxx'
Token = "xxxxx"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)


def startloop(queue):
    global gpid
    while True:
        print('Starting search for new entry')
        try:
            bot.send_message('xxxxxx', 'Looking for new entry...')
            # Restante do seu código...
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Erro ao enviar mensagem Telegram: {e}')
            tm.sleep(30)`
        
        verify_m_number = get_m_number()
        print(verify_m_number)
        if verify_m_number == 1:
            mlist = updatematchlist()
            while len(mlist) == 0:
                mlist = updatematchlist()
            mlist = updatematchlist()
            print(mlist)
            pattern = r'\((.*?)\)'
            matches = re.findall(pattern, mlist[0][2])
            pl1 , pl2 = matches

            patterntm = r'\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z\s\d]+) \((.*?)\)'
            matchestm = re.findall(patterntm, mlist[0][2])

            tm1 = matchestm[0][0]
            tm2 = matchestm[1][0]
            
            hEm = mlist[0][1].split('\n')[1].split(':')

            print(hEm)

            mint = str(getnt().minute).zfill(2)
            hr = str(getnt().hour).zfill(2)

            print("hEm[0]:", str(hEm[0]).zfill(2))
            print("hEm[1]:", hEm[1])
            print("hr:", hr)
            print("mint:", mint)

            
            med = overunderstat(pl1, pl2)
            if str(hEm[0]).zfill(2) != hr: print('different hr, looking for more')
    
            if str(hEm[0]).zfill(2) == hr and (int(mint) < int(hEm[1]) or (mint == '00' and hEm[1] != '00')):

                print('got it')
                event_minute = int(hEm[1])
                print(event_minute)
                event_second = 0
                current_minute = int(mint)
                current_second = int(getnt().second)
                print(pl1, pl2)
                
                # Aguardar até o próximo minuto
                time_to_sleep = (event_minute - current_minute - 1) * 60 + (60 - current_second)
                time_to_sleep = time_to_sleep - (time_to_sleep/3)
                time_to_sleep = round(float(time_to_sleep), 1)

                print(time_to_sleep)

                tm.sleep(time_to_sleep)
                # if (mint - hEm[1]) > 3: 
                #     tm.sleep(60) 
                
                print('starting')
                mtchdata = []
                while len(mtchdata) == 0:
                    mtchdata = getmatchdata(pl1, pl2)
                    print(mtchdata)
                
                print(f'med: | {med} > mtchdata: | {mtchdata} ?')
                print(chkourate(med, mtchdata))
                
                odd = mtchdata[0].split("-")[1]
                if len(chkourate(med, mtchdata)) > 0:

                    calc = chkourate(med, mtchdata)
                    foundentry = (f"""
        Over Asiático ({mtchdata[0].split("-")[2]}) - @{odd}\n
{pl1}  vs {pl2}
({tm1}) vs ({tm2})\n""")

                    fnde_sent = bot.send_message(gpid, foundentry)
                    to_put = [fnde_sent.message_id, pl1, tm1, pl2, tm2, mtchdata, odd, calc]
                    queue.put(to_put)
                    tm.sleep(180)
                else:
                    tm.sleep(60)
                    continue
        elif verify_m_number == 2:
            mlist = updatematchlist()
            while len(mlist) == 0:
                mlist = updatematchlist()
            mlist = updatematchlist()
            print(f'\n\n\n{mlist}')
            pattern_pl = r'\((.*?)\)'
            matchespl_fi = re.findall(pattern_pl, mlist[0][2])
            pl1_fi , pl2_fi = matchespl_fi
#           __________________________________________________
            print(mlist)
            matchespl_se = re.findall(pattern_pl, mlist[1][2])
            pl1_se , pl2_se = matchespl_se
            ################################################
            ################################################
            pattern_tm = r'\b([A-Z][a-zA-Z\s\d]+) \((.*?)\)'
            matchestm_fi = re.findall(pattern_tm, mlist[0][2])
            tm1_fi = matchestm_fi[0][0]
            tm2_fi = matchestm_fi[1][0]
#           __________________________________________________
            matchestm_se = re.findall(pattern_tm, mlist[1][2])
            tm1_se = matchestm_se[0][0]
            tm2_se = matchestm_se[1][0]


            hEm = mlist[0][1].split('\n')[1].split(':')

            print(hEm)

            mint = str(getnt().minute).zfill(2)
            hr = str(getnt().hour).zfill(2)

            print("hEm[0]:", str(hEm[0]).zfill(2))
            print("hEm[1]:", hEm[1])
            print("hr:", hr)
            print("mint:", mint)

            
            med_fi = overunderstat(pl1_fi, pl2_fi)
            med_se = overunderstat(pl1_se, pl2_se)
            
            if str(hEm[0]).zfill(2) != hr: print('different hr, looking for more')
    
            if str(hEm[0]).zfill(2) == hr and (int(mint) < int(hEm[1]) or (mint == '00' and hEm[1] != '00')):

                print('got it')
                event_minute = int(hEm[1])
                print(event_minute)
                event_second = 0
                current_minute = int(mint)
                current_second = int(getnt().second)
                print(f'First: ({pl1_fi},{pl2_fi})\nSecond:({pl1_se},{pl2_se})')
                
                # Aguardar até o próximo minuto
                time_to_sleep = (event_minute - current_minute - 1) * 60 + (60 - current_second)
                time_to_sleep = time_to_sleep - (time_to_sleep/3)
                time_to_sleep = round(float(time_to_sleep), 1)

                print(time_to_sleep)

                tm.sleep(time_to_sleep)
                # ['Over-2.1-2.5', 'Under-1.67-2.5']
                
                print('starting')
                mtchdata_fi = []
                mtchdata_se = []
                
                fi_ver = 0
                se_ver = 0
                while len(mtchdata_fi) == 0 or len(mtchdata_se) == 0:
                    mtchdata_fi = getmatchdata(pl1_fi, pl2_fi)
                    mtchdata_se = getmatchdata(pl1_se, pl2_se)

                    print(f'mdata_fi: {mtchdata_fi} | mdata_se: {mtchdata_se}')

                    if len(mtchdata_fi) > 0 or len(mtchdata_se) > 0:
                        fi_ver = len(chkourate(med_fi, mtchdata_fi))
                        se_ver = len(chkourate(med_se, mtchdata_se))                                
                        if  fi_ver > 0:
                            mtchdata_se = ['Over-1.85-0.5']
                            break
                        
                        elif  se_ver > 0:
                            mtchdata_fi = ['Over-1.85-0.5']
                            break
                
                mtchdata_fi = getmatchdata(pl1_fi, pl2_fi)
                mtchdata_se = getmatchdata(pl1_se, pl2_se)

                xmidfi = float(med_fi) - 0.5
                xmidse = float(med_se) - 0.5

                print(f'med_fi: | {xmidfi} > mtchdata_fi: | {mtchdata_fi} ?')
                print(f'med_se: | {xmidse} > mtchdata_se: | {mtchdata_se} ?')
                # ['Over-2.1-2.5', 'Under-1.67-2.5']



                if fi_ver > 0:
                    mtchdata = mtchdata_fi
                    med = med_fi

                    pl1 = pl1_fi
                    pl2 = pl2_fi
                    tm1 = tm1_fi
                    tm2 = tm2_fi


                    odd = mtchdata[0].split("-")[1]
                    calc = chkourate(med, mtchdata)
                    foundentry = (f"""
        Over Asiático ({mtchdata[0].split("-")[2]}) - @{odd}\n
{pl1}  vs {pl2}
({tm1}) vs ({tm2})\n""")

                    fnde_sent = bot.send_message(gpid, foundentry)
                    print("message suposed to be sent")
                    print(f'messageid: {fnde_sent.message_id}')
                    to_put = [fnde_sent.message_id, pl1, tm1, pl2, tm2, mtchdata, odd, calc]
                    queue.put(to_put)
                    tm.sleep(180)

                elif se_ver > 0:
                    mtchdata = mtchdata_se
                    med = med_se
                    
                    pl1 = pl1_se
                    pl2 = pl2_se
                    tm1 = tm1_se
                    tm2 = tm2_se


                    odd = mtchdata[0].split("-")[1]
                    calc = chkourate(med, mtchdata)
                    foundentry = (f"""
        Over Asiático ({mtchdata[0].split("-")[2]}) - @{odd}\n
{pl1}  vs {pl2}
({tm1}) vs ({tm2})\n""")

                    fnde_sent = bot.send_message(gpid, foundentry)
                    print("message suposed to be sent")
                    print(f'messageid: {fnde_sent.message_id}')
                    to_put = [fnde_sent.message_id, pl1, tm1, pl2, tm2, mtchdata, odd, calc]
                    queue.put(to_put)
                    tm.sleep(180)
                else:
                    tm.sleep(60)
                    continue
        # except Exception as e:
        #     bot.send_message('6162137618', f'Excpetion:\n\n{type(e)}\n{e}\n{e.__traceback__}')
        #     tm.sleep(4)
        #     continue
        else:
            print(verify_m_number)
            tm.sleep(3)


def send_message_process(queue__):
    global gpid
    print('process started')
    while True:
        queue_data = queue__.get()
        
        if queue_data is not None:
            print(f"got queue_data: {queue_data}")
            msg_id = queue_data[0]
            pl1 = queue_data[1]
            tm1 = queue_data[2]
            pl2 = queue_data[3]
            tm2 = queue_data[4]
            mtchdata = queue_data[5]
            odd = queue_data[6]
            calc = queue_data[7]
            tm.sleep(1200)
            result = getfinalresult(pl1, tm1, pl2, tm2)
            sc_tm1, sc_tm2 = map(int, result.split("x"))
            totalgl = int(sc_tm1) + int(sc_tm2)
            resultmsg_green = (f"""
Over Asiático ({mtchdata[0].split("-")[2]}) - @{odd}\n
{pl1}  vs {pl2}
({tm1}) vs ({tm2})
\U00002705\U00002705\U00002705\U00002705 
GREEN\n""")

            resultmsg_red = (f"""
Over Asiático ({mtchdata[0].split("-")[2]}) - @{odd}\n
{pl1}  vs {pl2}
({tm1}) vs ({tm2})
\U0000274C\U0000274C\U0000274C\U0000274C
RED\n""")
            
            if float(totalgl) > float(calc):
                try:
                    bot.edit_message_text(gpid, msg_id, resultmsg_green)
                    print("Message edited: GREEN")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error editing message: {e}... Trying again")
                    try:
                        bot.edit_message_text(gpid, msg_id, resultmsg_green)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print('Failed to edit message... Continuing loop')
                        continue
            elif float(totalgl) <= float(calc):
                try:
                    bot.edit_message_text(gpid, msg_id, resultmsg_red)
                    print("Message edited: RED")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error editing message: {e}... Trying again")
                    try:
                        bot.edit_message_text(gpid, msg_id, resultmsg_red)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print('Failed to edit message... Continuing loop')
                        continue
        tm.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    match_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()


    search_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=startloop, args=(match_queue,))

    send_message_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=send_message_process, args=(match_queue,))

    search_process.start()
    send_message_process.start()

    search_process.join()
    send_message_process.join()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation linked below for telebot, specifically for the edit_message_text method. You're passing the parameters in the wrong order, the resultmsg should be the first parameter passed. The corrected code would look like bot.edit_message_text(resultmsg_x, gpid, msg_id)

[Telebot](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.edit_message_text)